# Flex 4: Window's minimum size is too big

Tags: apache-flex, air, window, size

I tell the window to create with a size of 32x32

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       width="32"
                       height="32">
```

but it appears like this

[image]

The yellow box is an image that's 32x32.

Comment: what else do you have in the windowed app?

Comment: what is the yellow, what is the pink? is it just paint, or an actual screenshot? where is the code for the colors?

Comment: For the record, I don't believe such a small window size is possible on Windows and probably not on OS X either. This is to prevent an app from opening which hides the close buttons and cannot be closed in a normal fashion.

Comment: @JoshJanusch It's possible, I've done 32x32 windows on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

try setting minWidth=32 minHeight=32

Answer (score 0):

You have something in your window that is more than 32X32 so the window got resized to fit its content, sharing your full code will help us finding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The AIR application config xml file has a minwidth property. I assume you're on windows. In that case, the close, minimize, fullscreen buttons should always be visible, so you can't make smaller window (try resizing notepad.exe to understand). If you want smaller, you have to make a chromeless application / window (again in the config xml). That will allow you to create 1x1 px windows as well, but you'll have to add your own close button.

```
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
```